# Is every decidable language accepted by a turing machine?

Tags: terminology, computer-science

I am taking a cs class and the lecture slides are not very complete on this topic. can somebody clarify? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; this is the definition of “decidable language”.  A synonym is [recursive language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_language).

The relevant passage in Wikipedia says:

> A formal language is **recursive** if there exists a total Turing machine (a Turing machine that halts for every given input) that, when given a finite sequence of symbols as input, accepts it if belongs to the language and rejects it otherwise. Recursive languages are also called **decidable**.